# How can I shift my contacts from Outlook onto another platform?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, contacts

I have both (personal and business) contacts in Outlook and have not shared the access permission with anyone in the company.
Now, I would like to share my contacts with my office colleagues (only business contacts), but on another platform and not in Outlook. Which platform can help me do this (preferably for free)?

Answer (score 1):

It is very straightforward.

Outlook, Contacts window,  File, Open/Export, Import/Export and then export your Contacts as a CSV file.

The Outlook database is proprietary so CSV is the main interchange format.

[image]

Comment: Agree, the import/export feature in Outlook should be able to help about your issue.